# EXCEL、OLAPキューブ系関数の使い方。値ではなく軸の要素を抜き出したい場合

Tags: excel, sql-server

ピボットテーブルより**OLAPツール＞数式に変換**で

```
=CUBEMEMBER("OLAP",{"[00_カレンダ軸].[07_年月日].&[2014-04-01T00:00:00]","[54_商品情報共通軸].[01_商品コード].&[2611113719239]","[56_商品販売軸].[売価税抜].&[2686]"})
```

と出るようなものがあるとします。この式に変換したセルは「2686」が表示されていた軸部分です。
この時、商品コードとカレンダーからは一意の「売価税抜」が抜き出す事が出来ます。
今回その一意の売価税抜を呼び出したいのですが、上の数式に変換したものでは[2686]と指定されてしまっています。

この値を伏せて、コードとカレンダーからどのように抜き出すかわかる方いませんか？
どう書いていいのやらわからなく、情報が少ないかもしれませんが、何が必要かもわからないので聞いてください。よろしくお願いいたします。